# TineMCE doesn't initiate ajax-loaded textarea

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ajax, tinymce

I use $.ajax() to load this piece of html into a div

```
<div class="board-container">
    <form method="post" action="functions.php">
        <input type="hidden" name="function" value="set_boards">
        <div class="row-fluid">
            <div class="span6">
                <h3 class="dark">Student Board</h3>
                <textarea id="board_students" name="board_students">

                </textarea>
                <br>
            </div>
            <div class="span6">
                <h3 class="dark">Instructor Board</h3>
                <textarea id="board_instructors" name="board_instructors">

                </textarea>
                <br>
            </div>
        </div>
        <a href="#" class="btn btn-inverse btn-large btn-center">Update Boards</a>
    </form>
</div>

<script src="libs/tinymce/tinymce.min.js"></script>
<script src="js/board.js"></script>
```

And in the board.js, there's simply a TinyMCE initiation function.

```
$(function()
{
    tinymce.init({
        menubar : false,
        height: 700,
        selector: "#board_students"
    });
});
```

The ready() function should be called automatically due to ajax request. I've tested with alert and I know the function gets called.
The code works if the html is in the div by default, but when loaded through ajax, nothing happens. Why is that?

Comment: Just FYI, you can combine the two calls to tinymce.init() into one by combining the two selectors as `"#board_students,#board_instructors"`.

Comment: Is it right to assume that `data` returned in the AJAX call is exactly the `<div class="board-container">` in your first code block? You can now create a [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net) using their [AJAX API](http://doc.jsfiddle.net/use/echo.html) to reproduce this behavior. That will get you a lot more help.

Comment: Yes, the data returned is exactly the same as the posted html.

Comment: Can you put up a failing example on jsfiddle or something like that?

Comment: @V0R73X can you post your ajax load function ?

Answer (score 4):

This happens because your ajax loads content asynchronously and your tiny initialization function happens synchronously, may be the initialization happens before the content is placed into your dom. The another thing is you shouldn't load scripts in html data .
To solve this

If you want to load script async means you have to create a script tag element using js like

```
    var jsonp = document.createElement("script");
    jsonp.type = "text/javascript";
    jsonp.src = "libs/tinymce/tinymce.min.js";
    document.getElementsByTagName("body")[0].appendChild(jsonp);
```

or You can include `tinymce.min.js` in page itself and initialize the div after the content is loaded like

```
$.ajax({
         url: url,
         type: type,
         data: data,
         success: function(htmlData){
              $('#DivId').append(htmlData);
              //here internalize tiny mice when its available in dom   
              tinymce.init({
                 menubar : false,
                 height: 700,
                 selector: "#board_students"
              });
         }
   });
```

Try this and let me know if this works ... !!!

Answer (score 2):

The reason this is happening is because, The ajax adds your content AFTER --page load--.  Therefore, it's not reading and adding your code to the DOM, because you're adding this after the page is already loaded.

As many said, you can preload this info, or if you want to use AJAX.

The easiest way to initialize your code would be to add a .complete function at the end of your ajax call.  This says that when the ajax function is done running, continue with this action.

```
$.ajax({
  type: "POST", #GET/POST
  url: "some.url",
  data: {}
})
.complete(function() {
    tinymce.init({
    menubar : false,
    height: 700,
    selector: "#board_students"
  }
});
```

[Jquery Ajax Call](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/)

Answer (score 0):

The `<script>` blocks in your case will start execute in the same moment asynchronous, and just because tinymce is the biggest script, `tinymce.init` will fail.

You need load the scripts as additional cascade of ajax call:

```
$.get(...., function (){// first level, getting the html
    $.getScript(...., function (){// second level, getting <script src="libs/tinymce/tinymce.min.js"></script>
         // executing or loading js/board.js 
    });
});
```